# Как мотивировать сотрудников?

Tags: работа

Друзья, поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.

Допустим у Вас на работе Вы закрыли проект раньше срока. Вам дают премию? как она начисляется? по желанию руководства и хз в каком объеме? Или есть строгая формула по которой высчитывается? Если да. то какая она?

Если с программистами понятно, чем раньше сделают, тем лучше и для них и для компании, то как мотивировать дизайнера? Исходя из чего давать премию им? Ведь торопить их нельзя, это будет в ущерб качеству, будут рисовать быстрее, но херню. А не мотивировать никак, будут рисовать долго долго. Как быть тут? За что и когда давать премию?

Comment: А программисты, они написали, протестировали -- и всё? И ошибок там больше быть не могет? Крутые они у Вас...

Comment: ИМХО премию нужно платить за большой вклад в жизнь проекта и да, руководство, не общаясь с сотрудниками, естественно, не может определить его размер.

А вот платить за то, что быстро сделал, ИМХО, не самое верное решение т.к. скорость != качество, хотя, конечно, бывают исключения, а именно те случаи когда сроки намного важнее качества, тогда да ( но, чем чаще вы работаете над такими проектами, тем вы ближе к темной стороне силы )

btw премия не должная быть единственным мотивирующим фактором, скорее так можно сказать человеку - молодец, спасибо, так держать.

Comment: Почему то мне пришла в голову старая добрая идея родом из СССР. Как насчет того чтобы тому кто закончил  что то делать раньше срока вместо премии увеличить план?

Comment: @butteff,    Ведь торопить их нельзя, это будет в ущерб качеству, будут рисовать быстрее, но не то. гоните их в шею, вот и весь разговор.

Comment: Награды - самая большая помеха для когнитивной деятельности. [Youtube:RSA Animate - Drive: The surprising truth about what motivates us](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Исследование по заказу работодателей?

     Учил цыган лошадь не есть. Совсем научил, жаль померла.

Comment: @alexlz невнимательно смотрели ролик. Если сотрудник думает только о деньгах, которых ему не хватает, то качества вы от него не добьетесь, он будет гнаться за легкими бонусами и гнать шнягу - типа "больше сделаешь больше получишь". при достаточной зарплате, если давать большие бонусы за невыполнимое или суперсложное, то ему при его зарплате будет влом напрягаться и при этом оставаться довольным имеющейся зарплатой.

Comment: @avp, полностью поддерживаю. Ишь какие нежные. Либо работай как надо, либо трудовую книжку в зубы и вперёд, с песнями.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, и какой Ваш краткий *положительный* (отрицательный Вы уже привели в первом комментарии) резюм ролика?

Что нужно для когнитивной деятельности?

Помнится, Резерфорд на эту тему говорил что-то вроде "Хлеб, масло, но не джем".

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Да я вообще ролик не смотрел. Был бы он на русском -- куда ни шло. (Кстати, для сведения -- я изучал немецкий. Правда, безуспешно)

А упрощения -- они до добра никогда не доводят.

Comment: @avp, ну ролик статистический да, типа и для MIT и для индусов мат. поощрения работают одинаково плохо. хорошо работают нематериальные поощрения - свобода принятия решений - чем конкретно заниматься сейчас среди нескольких имеющихся заданий, самостоятельное определение сроков. что-то еще может быть...  
Понятно, что это все далековато от практики, потому что двух одинаковых контор не бывает, везде свои закидоны и мотивация должна быть в каждом отдельном случае своя, особенно в наших конторах.  
ЗЫ Про мат. бонусы в целом согласен с ответом @Barmaley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я исповедую следующий подход в основе которого лежат 2 леммы:

1. Постоянная мотивация нужна только для грузчиков/кладовщиков (то есть неквалицированному персоналу - к коим прогеров затруднительно отнести)
2. Формализация системы премирования в творческой деятельности или невозможна или это зло.

Не берусь ручаться что леммы верны на 100%, но что то есть то есть - *в этом месте можно бросаться камнями, плеваться и проч. - разрешаю*

Исходя из этого схема такая:

1. Платим прогерам постоянный оклад без премиальных и проч.
2. Раз в полгода, в год по завершению прожекта - платим нормальный бонус - сопоставимый с 2-3 окладами или больше.

Недостатки системы понятны - доброхоты наверняка в каментах умножат их. Укажу один главный недостаток: в такой системе требуется наличие мудрого начальника, а не того который будет слушать льстецов и проч. мусор.

По преимуществам:

1. В течение пары-тройки месяцев сразу же отсеивается временный элемент, те кто пришли не работать, а просто просиживать. Уходят либо сами, либо начальство бдит и следит. См. Лемму №1.
2. До бонусов доживают только старожилы, то есть те на которых держится прожект.

Comment: по каким параметрам начислять бонус? желательно в процентах от размера бонуса...

Comment: Я бы бюджетировал 20-30% от месячного оклада, то есть за год накопится 240-360%

Comment: если давать бонусы только по завершении, то можно лишиться отличных спецов, которые просто сразу уйдут.

Comment: @IVsevolod здесь вопрос в том, что лучше: отличный спец не преданный делу, или отличный спец преданный делу. Я считаю, что лучше второй вариант. Система нацелена на выделение фанатов.

Comment: Правильная система. 

Отличные спецы сразу не уйдут по двум причинам:

1. Они приходят только на *интересную* работу.

2. Они рассчитывают (и по большей части обосновано) все-таки получить бонусы.

Comment: @Barmaley у отличного спеца может быть семья, которую нужно обеспечивать. И то что бонусы будут где-то когда-то в будущем может в итоге не устроить их. Также их может волновать мысль, а не обманут ли меня с премией по завершению проекта?

@avp начинающие отличные спецы - ищут интересную работу. А спецы с опытом могут оценивать еще свою работу, сколько они стоят. А на счет бонусов - необходимо сделать доверительное отношение с ними, чтобы они не ставили под сомнение вашу честность.

Спустя какое то время, отличный спец в любом случае должен влиться в коллектив, мотивация может другая появиться

Comment: @IVsevolod, то что спец оценивает свою работу "*не ниже, чем ...*", IMHO очевидно.

Естественно, Вы не пойдете работать за деньги (без бонусов, т.е. "синица в руках"), меньшие, чем Вам нужны.

Это, так сказать, необходимое условие для получения спеца в проект.

А вот эффективность и продолжительность его работы зависят от ряда факторов:

- коллектив (в т.ч. его средний профессиональный уровень);

- лично интерересная спецу тема (и миниколлектив по ней);

- график работы;

- дополнительное вознагрождение (бонусы).

- признание заслуг;


Понятно, что порядок (и состав) зависит от индивида.

Comment: @avp совершенно согласен.

Comment: @Barmaley видимо мой вопрос был неточен...

допустим за пол года скопилось (6`*`50к)*0.10 = 30000р бонуса, больше этой суммы человек не получит всё равно.

------
**теперь сколько и за что должен получить человек?** (из 30к) 

в скобках указан бонус который видит  работник (за 6,12 мес)

допустим: 

 1. 10к (0.010%) - чистота кода документация и т.п.
 2. 5к  (0.005%) - возможность модернизации (или
   простота модернизации)
 3. 15к (0.015%) - скорость работы и требования
   ресурсов


понятное дело что если все сроки сорваны или  заказчик не принял заказ, то вся команда лишается бонусов

Answer (score 0):

*Вообще вопрос не совсем вписывается в тематику. Если бы речь шла о поощрении IT специалистов то ответили бы лучше.*

Премии для созидательных личностей - зло.
Премия это непрозрачный система, которая очень часто не отвечает за реальную работу и трудозатраты человека. Многое зависит от

- обратил ли внимание начальник.
- какое у начальника настроение.
- какие взаимоотношения между ним и коллегами,коллективом и начальником.
  Если премию получают незаслуженно, то это сильно бьёт по коллективу.

Один из выходов:
Бонусная система оплаты труда.

Разрабатывается прозрачная схема начисления бонусов для конкретных должностей. Если должность это позволяет.

Скажем за 5 изображений стандартного размера полагается бонус 500 у.е.
Изображения должны соответстовать стандартам качества и быть одобрены ответственным лицом.
Исполнителю рекомендуется заранее консультироваться по вопросам соответствия качества, с указанным ответственным лицом.
Исполнитель должен понимать, что СПЕШКА НЕ ПОМОЖЕТ заработать дополнительные у.е, так как она часто ведет к снижению качества продукта, и бракованию изображения ответственным лицом.
Дисциплинарные нарушения будут приводить к снятию бонусных очков.

Преимущества:

- При правильном составлении всё будет зависеть от работника.

Недостатки:

- Если у компании туго с деньгами, то такая схема либо серьезно ударит по бюджету, либо резко снизит авторитет компании из-за нарушения сроков выплат.
- Может получится, что деятельность работника будет нерентабельной, так как получая дополнительные бонусы он зарабатывает, но для компании его дополнительный труд не приносит особых дивидендов.
- Не так то просто разработать бонусную систему для многих специальностей. 
  Например грузчику надо за 1 день загрузить мешки с мукой в вагон поезда. Если он это сделает за 1 час, 3 часа или 23 часа разницы никакой не будет. За что тут премию платить? Главное чтобы успел за 24 часа иначе не получит зарплату.
  Но здесь речь идет о дизайне поэтому вполне возможно прикрутить бонусы.
- Работает только при честном и порядочном персонале.
- В России малопопулярна. Принимается с неохотой.

[А вообще здесь можно почитать про разные схемы:](http://www.trudaga.ru/index.php?nomer=807)

Comment: мне например жутко раздражает ситуация в моей фирме, когда менеджеры получают большие премии по продажам, а тем, кто разрабатывает ее ничего не дают, а тем кто ее делает дают по минимуму... и это серьезно демотивирует на работу.

Comment: Я как-то не уловил чем отличается бонус от премии?

Answer (score 0):

Напишу свое мнение по этому поводу. Премия действительно может как сказаться положительно, так и отрицательно. Дать слишком много - подумают о халяве, расслабятся, или же наоборот поверят что о них заботятся и начнут стараться. Дать слишком мало или не дать - подумают что их труд не уважают, и негативное отношение будет расти, или же наоборот - начнут больше стараться.

В любом случае, руководитель / начальник должен сделать дружный коллектив, чтобы рабочие уважали своего начальника. Вот тогда на них влияние з/п мало будет сказываться. Должно быть взаимоуважение сотрудник - руководитель.

Советую прочитать книку **7 навыков высокоэффективных людей** может в жизни как руководителям, так и сотрудникам.